# Qt and parsing JSON data in C++

Tags: python, c++, json, qt

I have a QJsonObject in my code and It looks something like what is posted below (once converted to a string in python), (with a lot more entries of the same form). Suppose I want to group all of the name attributes in an array. In python I would convert my Json String to a dictionary and then populate this list as follows. How can I do this in c++ with qt?

1.

```
CountryNameList = []
For i in range len(CountryDictionary[1]):
      CountryNameList.append CountryDictionary[1][i]["name"]
```

// Below is what the JSON file looks like:

```
[
    {
        "per_page": "50",
        "total": 264,
        "page": 1,
        "pages": 6
    },
    [
        {
            "longitude": "-70.0167",
            "name": "Aruba",
            "region": {
                "id": "LCN",
                "value": "Latin America & Caribbean (all income levels)"
            },
            "adminregion": {
                "id": "",
                "value": ""
            },
            "iso2Code": "AW",
            "capitalCity": "Oranjestad",
            "latitude": "12.5167",
            "incomeLevel": {
                "id": "NOC",
                "value": "High income: nonOECD"
            },
            "id": "ABW",
            "lendingType": {
                "id": "LNX",
                "value": "Not classified"
            }
        },
        {
            "longitude": "69.1761",
            "name": "Afghanistan",
            "region": {
                "id": "SAS",
                "value": "South Asia"
            },
            "adminregion": {
                "id": "SAS",
                "value": "South Asia"
            },
            "iso2Code": "AF",
            "capitalCity": "Kabul",
            "latitude": "34.5228",
            "incomeLevel": {
                "id": "LIC",
                "value": "Low income"
            },
            "id": "AFG",
            "lendingType": {
                "id": "IDX",
                "value": "IDA"
            }
        },
  ] ]
```

Comment: Create a [QJsonDocument](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html#fromJson) with `QJsonDocument::fromJson()`

Comment: @KarstenKoop After having converted how can I access the elements in the way described above.

Comment: with some `ToQVariantMap` ?

Comment: [QJsonDocument::array()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html#array) gives you an array over which you can iterate, using e.g. `foreach`

Comment: @KarstenKoop I had success with making an array and then accessing the first element, but then how can I convert that first element which is a JsonValue to a dictionary or access each of its "name" attributes depending on an index.

Comment: Did you have a look at [the QJsonValue documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonvalue.html)?

Comment: @KarstenKoop yes and I am still very confused. So first I get a QJsonDocument from my QJasonObject then I use that to create an array, whose 2nd element is what I want, a QJsonValue (in this case an array) according to isArray() method. Now lets say this QJsonValue is called CountriesArray. What type of array is this and how can I access elements by index and then convert them to maps so I can query the data.

Comment: If your object is a nested array, you call `toArray`, if it's a string, you call `toString`, if it's an object, you call `toObject` which gives you a QJsonObject, from which you can query keys and values, or convert it to a QVariantMap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample how to read and parse your json:

```
#include <QtCore>

int main() {
    QFile input_file("input.json");

    if (!input_file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
        qDebug() << "Can't open file";
        return 1;
    }

    QJsonParseError parse_error;

    //read and parse from file
    QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(input_file.readAll(), 
                                               &parse_error);

    //check parsing errors
    if (parse_error.error != QJsonParseError::NoError) {
        qDebug() << "Parsing error:" << parse_error.errorString();
        return 1;
    }

    //this is top level arraya
    QJsonArray arr_doc = doc.array();

    //this is array of country objects
    QJsonArray arr_countries = arr_doc[1].toArray();

    //list to save result
    QList<QString> country_name_list;

    //c++11 style for cycle. Iterate over countries.
    for (const auto& country: arr_countries) {
        //getting name of country and convert to string, append to result
        country_name_list.append(country.toObject()["name"].toString());
    }

    qDebug() << country_name_list;

    return 0;
}
```

Don't forget add to .pro file:

```
CONFIG += c++11
```

And remove comma from your json:

```
     }
        },
  ] ]
```